# Is it correct to use "can be commonly seen" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Another resistor can be commonly seen around us is marked with E96 Standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with *can be commonly seen*. However, the sentence is awkward as it stands for other reasons.

There is no problem with parsing the sentence—until everything comes to a halt when you get to *is*, which doesn't fit with what went before.

There are a few ways it could be made better; you can insert a *that*, you can insert a semicolon and a pronoun, or you can remove *can be*:

> Another resistor that can be commonly seen around us is marked with E96 Standard.
>   Another resistor can be commonly seen around us; it is marked with E96 Standard.
>   Another resistor commonly seen around us is marked with E96 Standard.

The reason the sentence is awkward without any of those changes is because, without them, it's ambiguous how it should actually be interpreted.